# BackgroundWorker with MySql not working properly

Tags: c#, mysql, for-loop, insert, backgroundworker

I have a method which inserts data into a `MySql` database within a `for loop`.

The amount of inserts can be a lot so my program freezes during inserting.

So i wanted to try to put it in a `BackgroundWorker`, however it isn't working as planned...

After some inserts I get an exception that my connection is already opened

Here's how I do it:

```
if (dbPos.connOpen())
{
    // inserts one row, works fine because data is present in db
    dbPos.checkOut(prijs, wie);

    // this works for a few inserts, 
    // but after a couple it will tell me my conn is already open
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // inserts many rows
}
dbPos.connClose();
```

My `BackgroundWorker` method:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chartList.Count; i++)
    {
        switch (this.countChart(i))
        {
            ... Do work ... // insert rows
        }
    }
}
```

And my method that will actually insert values into database:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    ... parameters ....
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

So how can i solve this mysterious problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're closing your connection:

```
if (dbPos.connOpen())
{
    // inserts one row, works fine because data is present in db
    dbPos.checkOut(prijs, wie);

    // This *starts* the work, but doesn't block
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // inserts many rows        
}
// This happens while the background work is still occurring
dbPos.connClose();
```

You should move the `dbPos.connOpen()` and `connClose()` calls into the `BackgroundWorker`'s `DoWork` handler.  This will allow the connection to stay open while the work occurs.

Comment: Thank you, good sir. In my first insert method I open and close my connection there. Then for the many inserts i put open and close in the `DoWork` handler. Works great !